# Working remotely from another EU country

Tags: schengen, europe, work, taxes

I work in Finland for a Finnish company. Due to covid, I work remotely all the time. Given this situation, I would like to work from another Schengen country for couple of weeks. What are the laws that allow or ban me from working couple of weeks from another Schengen country?

Edit: I'm a non-EU national and I have a resident permit A.

Comment: Besides any travel restrictions related to Covid-19 this is not really a travel question. Has more to do with labor laws in Finland. Many European countries (and I presume Finland too) have restrictions on work home from another country. Your contract with your employer may also restrict what you are (not) allowed to do. We are not really in a position to judge your personal situation.

Comment: I don't know what the laws here are, and they probably vary depending on if you are an EU citizen or a residence permit holder. But, as a practical matter, nobody's gonna know (except possibly your employer) if you do this for a couple of weeks.

Comment: What is your immigration status in Finland? Without knowing that, this question is too broad.  I have therefore voted to close it as "needing details or clarity."  Please edit the question to add that information.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: This would seem to have nothing to do with travel.  The "workplace" site has lots of (lame) visa questions about working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This belongs on [Expatriates Stack Exchange](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions).

With your Finnish residence permit you can **travel** to other Schengen countries as if you had a 90/180 short term visa. Simplified, you can travel to **talk about work**, but you cannot travel to **do work**. In certain jobs the line can be hard to draw.